# I don't recieve onIabPurchaseFinished when purchase is finished

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(End.this, "resurrect", 10001,
new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {@Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {

        Log.v("end:iabfinished:result", result.toString());
        Log.v("end:iabfinished:info", info.toString());


        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //here's some code which was never executed
        } else if (result.getResponse() != IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED) Toast.makeText(End.this, result.getMessage() + " (ERROR CODE " + result.getResponse() + ")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(info, new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
                    Log.v("end:ouconsumeF:purchase", purchase.toString());
                    Log.v("end:ouconsumeF:result", result.toString());
                }
            });
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.v("end:throwableonconsume", e.toString()); //debug
        } //really dont know how it works
    }
}, payload);
```

This code successfully opens google play fragment in which I make purchase. But onIabPurchaseFinished isn't called when purchase is successfully finished. The only situation when it is called is when I get error 7 "Item Already Owned"

I use code copied from sample project "TrivialDrive" (com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.util)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just forgotten to write onActivityResult:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
    if (mHelper == null) return;

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
```